# Decreasing permutation

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, solution-verification, permutations

A permutation σ of the set [n] = {1, 2, ..., n} is decreasing if for every i < j, it holds that σ(i) > σ(j). How many decreasing permutations of [n] are there?

My attempt:

Since 1<i for all i in {2, ..., n}, we know that σ(1)=n. Otherwise we would have a j with σ(j)=n>σ(1), but 1<j.
Same argument: σ(2)=n-1
.
.
.
It follows, that there is exactly one decreasing permutation, if n is even. And there is no permutation if n is not even.

I dont see what is wrong, but it also seems suspiciously easy. Can someone confirm?

Comment: Suspiciously easy is right... of course there is only one decreasing permutation.  Perhaps you mean to talk about decreasing *functions* which are not necessarily permutations?

Comment: Why isn't there one if $n$ is even?  There is one.  If $n=2$ there is $2,1$

Comment: Why aren't there odd ones?

Comment: The permutation which sends each $k \in [n]$ on $n+1-k$ is the only decreasing permutation, whatever the parity of $n$ is.

Answer (score 1):

Fix a decreasing bijection $\sigma:[n]\rightarrow[n]$ and let $i\in[n]$.
Let $\mathcal L=\{\sigma(j):j\in[i-1]\}$ and $\mathcal U=\{\sigma(j):j\in[n]\setminus[i]\}$. Since $\sigma$ is a bijection, we have $|\mathcal L|=i-1$ and $|\mathcal U|=n-i$.
Since we have $j>i$ for all $j\in[n]\setminus[i]$, we have $\max\mathcal U<\sigma(i)$ and thereby $n-i<\sigma(i)$. On the other hand, since we have $j<i$ for all $j\in[i-1]$, we have $\min\mathcal L>\sigma(i)\ge n-i+1$ and hence $\mathcal L=[n]\setminus[n-i+1]$. This shows that $\sigma(i)=n-i+1$. Thus, the only candidate for a decreasing bijection is $\sigma:[n]\rightarrow[n]$, $i\mapsto n-i+1$. We easily verify that $\sigma$ is indeed a bijection.